# How to change the values on text changed event of the cell of datagridview using C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview in which i want to add the value to the value of the cell which i subtracted from the value of the cell whose index is -1 of that cell.

Answer (score 1):

The event you are looking for is CellValueChanged. Below is an example of using if (where I add the new value of one cell to the cell beside it)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingList<Values> values = new BindingList<Values>();
        values .Add(new Values() { ValueOne = 1, ValueTwo = 2});
        values .Add(new Values() { ValueOne = 1, ValueTwo = 2});
        values .Add(new Values() { ValueOne = 1, ValueTwo = 2 });

        dataGridView1.DataSource = values ;          

        dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValueChanged);
    }

    void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];

        if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["ValueOne"].Index)
        {
            DataGridViewCell neighbour = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex + 1, e.RowIndex];

            neighbour.Value = ((int)cell.Value) + ((int)neighbour.Value);
        }
    }
}

public class Values
{
    public int ValueOne { get; set; }
    public int ValueTwo { get; set; }
}
```